# Try Except Block not passing after correct input

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I'm new to Python and coding in general, and ran into a bit of a bug in my code. Whenever i type in the wrong input in my Try/Except code block, the console prints "Invalid input" However, whenever i type in the correct phrase in the console, it still says "Invalid input". I looked online to try to fix this issue (notated with ##) with these lines of code, but i still get the same issue.

For example, I would type in "Mad Libs" with correct case and everything, and still get "Invalid input" from my != command. Could this be easily fixed by formatting in a different way? This happens with all 3 games.

How can this issue be addressed? Thanks in advance!

```
def game_selection(): ##
    pass ##


while True: ##
    try:
        playerChoice = input("So, which game would you like to play?: ")
        if playerChoice != "Mad Libs":
            print("Invalid input")
        elif playerChoice != "Guessing Game":
            print("Invalid input")
        elif playerChoice != "Language Maker":
            print("Invalid input")
        continue ##
    except:
        print("Invalid Input")


game_selection() ##

print("Got it! " + playerChoice + " it is!")
sleep(2)

if playerChoice == "Mad Libs":
    print("Initializing 'Mad Libs'.")
    sleep(.5)
    print("Welcome to MadLibs, " + playerName + "! There are a few simple rules to the game.")
    print("All you have to do is enter in a phrase or word that is requested of you.")
    playerReady = input("Ready to begin? Y/N")
```

Comment: Think about the logic of your if and else ifs.

Comment: if you type "Mad Libs" first `if` is not True so it goes next check (first `elif`). At `elif` the check is True because "Mad Libs" is different from "Guessing Game". So the output `Invalid input` is coming from this check.

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing lool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, this code will not work because if I enter "Mad Libs" the first if will not pass and so it will pass to all the others elif. So you can't take this approach.
What I advice you to do is to check if the playerChoice string is in an array

```py
from time import sleep

while True:
   playerChoice = input("So, which game would you like to play?:")
   allowedGames = ["Mad Libs", "Guessing Game", "Language Maker"]
   if playerChoice not in allowedGames:
      print('Invalid input!')
   else:
      break

print("Got it! " + playerChoice + " it is!")
sleep(2)

if playerChoice == "Mad Libs":
    print("Initializing 'Mad Libs'.")
    sleep(.5)
    print("Welcome to MadLibs, " + playerName + "! There are a few simple rules to the game.")
    print("All you have to do is enter in a phrase or word that is requested of you.")
    playerReady = input("Ready to begin? Y/N")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you asked it to answer invalid input anyway in this code

```
While True: ##
    try:
        playerChoice = input("So, which game would you like to play?: ")
        if playerChoice != "Mad Libs":
            print("Invalid input")
        elif playerChoice != "Guessing Game":
            print("Invalid input")
        elif playerChoice != "Language Maker":
            print("Invalid input")
        continue ##
    except:
        print("Invalid Input")
```